# How to compare battery level before and after an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, power-management

do you have link/tutorial for compare the battery level before and after an activity/computation process?

Comment: There are many links on battery usage in the **Related** column, over there -->

Answer (score 1):

For most devices, the granularity of reported battery changes is 1% of capacity. If your "activity/computation process" consumes more than 1% power, it had better be running for quite some time.

That being said, call `registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))`. Since `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a sticky broadcast, the `registerReceiver()` call will return the last broadcast `Intent`. Then, retrieve the `BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL` and `BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE` values to determine the battery level. Just bear in mind that:

- While `EXTRA_SCALE` is frequently 100, it is not always 100
- While `EXTRA_LEVEL` frequently changes in increments of 1 (e.g., 100, 99, 98), it does not always change in increments of 1